# Extract list name passed to function as string in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the name of the list I am passing to a function as a string.
The string extracted must be stored within the same function (so I can use it during the same call).

Example:

```
my_function <- function(obj, arg = NULL) {
  # obj is a list object that I pass to my_function()
  obj_string <- ... # obj_string is the name of the list I have just passed to my_function
}
```

so, if I write `my_function(list_name)`, `obj_string` must store "list_name".

I tried with `deparse(substitute(obj))` or `deparse(substitute(Transform))` but they don't work.
I have also tried `{{obj}}` but it won't work either.

Comment: `deparse(substitute(obj))` should work

Comment: If that doesn't work, make sure to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either `return` obj_string at the end of the function, or assign (`<<-`) it to the environment:

```
my_function <- function(obj, arg = NULL) {
  obj_string <- deparse(substitute(obj))
  obj_string
}

 #OR#

my_function <- function(obj, arg = NULL) {
  obj_string <<- deparse(substitute(obj))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `deparse/substitute`.  We don't need to create an object inside

```
 my_function <- function(obj, arg = NULL) { 
     deparse(substitute(obj))
}
```

-testing

```
> my_function(list_name)
[1] "list_name"
```

---

If we don't return anything.  Just assign to an object and get the value or wrap with `()` to print into console

```
 my_function <- function(obj, arg = NULL) { 
    obj_string <- deparse(substitute(obj))
}
```

-testing

```
> tmp <- my_function(list_name)
> tmp
[1] "list_name"
> > (my_function(list_name))
[1] "list_name"
```

Comment: this is weird, when I run deparse(substitute(obj)) I get back an insanely long output which looks more or less the content of the list... I wonder if I am using some package that is replacing the original deparse or substitute functions...

Comment: @GNicoletti Can you try on a fresh R session wihtout any packages loaded

Comment: I will, in the meantime - thank you very much for your answer! I also managed to find a solution myself (look the answer below)

Comment: I thought your question was about not printing the output into console as you did the `obj_string <-` in the last step

Comment: yes you are right, I wrote int the comment that it returns "list_name" but I meant that I successfully managed to store the correct string :)

Comment: Or if you want to print on the console just wrap with `(my_function(list_name))
`

Comment: deparse(substitute(obj)) works if I assign it to obj_string, but it doesn't if you just call it without assigning it. Thanks for the answer. Solved.

Comment: That is why I said to wrap with `()`

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to make it work myself (thanks to the other users who posted so far, I am going to test your answers too!)

```
as.character(as.list(match.call()[-1]$obj))
```

returns "list_name"